# Why I obtain this "NUnit.Framework.SuccessException" trying to debug a NUNIT test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am pretty new in **NUNIT** and I am experiencing the following stranhge behavior.

Into my test project I have this test class:

```
namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass("PASSED");
        }

    }
}
```

that at the moment contain only the **Test1()** method that should pass every time that it is executed (because I am using the **Assert.Pass()** method.

If I run this test it works fine and the test pass (green bar inside Visual Studio Test Explorer).

But if I try to debug this method (putting a breackpoint on the **Assert.Pass("PASSED");** line it give me this exception trying to executed the Pass() method:

```
Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Framework.SuccessException' in nunit.framework.dll
An exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.SuccessException' occurred in nunit.framework.dll but was not handled in user code
PASSED
```

The test anyway seems to be passed. But why am I obtaining this exception in debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Assert.Pass` does indeed throw an exception, which allows you to send a message to the test runner. You *very rarely* need to use an `Assert.Pass` as you don't need to do this for the test to pass. You can instead allow the test to complete.

Obviously, your real tests should assert *something*, but usually you'll be checking a value is as expected. When it is, there will be no exception.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Pass)...

> Since it causes an exception to be thrown, it is more efficient to simply allow the test to return

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to read documentation on the method used:

```
/// <summary>
/// Throws a <see cref="SuccessException"/> with the message and arguments
/// that are passed in. This allows a test to be cut short, with a result
/// of success returned to NUnit.
/// </summary>
```

https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Assert.cs#L105